# Given the sum of $k$ numbers, what is the maximum value of their product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb{N}.$ Given that $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=100,$ what is the maximum value of $P=x_1x_2\ldots x_k,$ and for what value of $k$ does this maximum occur?

This is a question from Tata Institute of Fundamental Research Grad School (TIFR GS) Exam $2023.$

My Attempt: From AM-GM, we know that $P\leq\left(\frac{100}{k}\right)^k.$ Now, consider the function $f(k)=\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^k.$ It has a maxima at $k=\frac{a}{e}.$ Putting $a=100,$ we get that $P$ is maximised when $k$ is around $36.$ Also, from the equality condition of AM-GM, we know that each of the $x_i$s is equal. So, putting $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_k=1,$ we get $k=100.$ $100$ is a far way from $36,$ so we ignore this. Similarly, putting $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_k=2,$ we get $k=50.$ We ignore this as well. However, equating each $x_i$ to 3 gives $k=33.333\ldots,$ which seems promising. So my thinking is that we should be aiming to maximise the numbers of $3$s in the product. Note that $100=3\times33+1.$ This gives $P=3^{33}.$ Also, $100=3\times32+4.$ This gives $P=4\times3^{32}.$ We can also write $100$ as $3\times31+7.$ This gives $P=7\times3^{31}.$ Comparing each value of $P$ we get, we see that $P=4\times3^{32}$ is the largest one. This is the correct answer, but my solution is very hand-wavy and not rigorous at all. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: To be clear, is $k$ a specific number that we know ahead of time before starting the problem?  For instance, are we asking "*Given the sum of 3 positive integers is 100, what is the maximum value of the product of those three numbers?*"  Or is $k$ able to change?  "*Given that a collection of positive integers has sum equal to $100$, what is the largest product that this collection of integers could have?*"

Comment: @JMoravitz, no, $k$ is allowed to change. That is why I considered different values of $k$ in my answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz, your second interpretation of my question is what I'm looking for: Given that a collection of positive integers has sum equal to $100,$ what is the largest product that this collection of integers could have?

Comment: I recommend rereading how you have written the question and rereading my first comment, and understanding why the way you have written the question then is wrong given the interpretation you intend the question to have.

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes, you are right. I hope the edit fixed it.